# login DN and password for osixia/phpLDAPAdmin docker image

Tags: docker, openldap

I am just getting started with LDAP. I downloaded the osixia openldap docker image and the phpLDAPAdmin:

[OpenLDAP](https://github.com/osixia/docker-openldap)

[LDAPAdmin](https://github.com/osixia/docker-phpLDAPadmin)

I created the containers this way:

```
docker run --name ldap -p 389:389 -p 689:689 -e LDAP_DOMAIN=localhost -e LDAP_ORGANISATION=MyOrganisation -e LDAP_ADMIN_PASSWORD=mypw -v D:\docker\LDAP\ldap:/var/lib/ldap -v D:\docker\LDAP\slapd:/etc/ldap/slapd.d -d osixia/openldap


docker run -p 6443:443 --env PHPLDAPADMIN_LDAP_HOSTS=172.17.0.4 --detach osixia/phpldapadmin
```

It seems to have worked: I can open the admin console and I can connect to LDAP from keycloak.

What I don't understand is, how do I log into the phpLDAPAdmin. What is the 
Login DN and password? Password is `mypw` in this cas I guess, but the login DN?

Answer (score 2):

phpLDAPadmin user name must be something like this.

```
cn=admin,dc=first_part_of_the_domain,dc=second_part_of_the_domain,dc=third__part_of_the_domain
```

as an example, `cn=admin,dc=example,dc=mail,dc=com`

Comment: what is domain name?  if i run openldap set "-e LDAP_DOMAIN=localhost",then: